# Can we retrive localstorage ,even we use sqlite storage in ionic 3 app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, native, ionic3

I already have a running App in Ionic 2 beta, and I am using local storage to store logged in `user_id` to check if the user is logged in or not.
Now I'll switch the app into Ionic 3, and now i am using SQLite storage of Ionic, so problem is, I don't want to ask for login again to my users after update the app from app store. I want to get device local storage and make entry in SQLite and remove.

Here what I do for Ionic 2 beta app

```
import { Storage, LocalStorage } from 'ionic-angular';

...

    constructor () {
        this.local = new Storage(LocalStorage);
    }

    this.local.set('user_id', user_id);
```

And in the Ionic 3 app:

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

...

    constructor(public local: Storage) {
        this.local.get('user_id').then((user_id) => {
            console.log('USER ID: ' + user_id);
        });
    }
    ...
```

Question: Now what I want, if user update his app then system first check for local storage is already set for the app, if yes then system set them as for new app and remove them, so that user will not need to signup again after update app.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you can do is First to check  the value of your local storage if you have any data in it.

like this i put this code inside my app.component

```
          //initialize the storage
           this.storage.get('credentials').then(data => {
                //check if data is null or no data yet.
                if (data != null) {

                  // you can do is to
                  this.nav.setRoot(login);

               } else {

                 //or is here is a logged user you can do
                 this.nav.setRoot(home);

                }
              }).catch(error => {

              });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, its pretty simple .
Just using the core javascript to get local storage as below :

```
let preLocalStorage =  window.localStorage;
let user_id   = preLocalStorage.getItem('user_id');
```

And then put the value in sqlite as below :

```
this.local.set('user_id',user_id);
```

It works perfect !

Thanks